# VBA MS Access Row 1 to last column

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I'm trying to figure out why this code works every other time I run it in Access.

I have a spreadsheet that is being built via access query and then exported to Excel.
Then I am running this to do a little formatting/cleanup. (It's suppose to select the cell in row 1 copy those values to the last column (in row 1) and then paste them in a specified cell.

It runs perfectly on the first run but I get a debug error if I run the same thing again.
Debug comes up on this line:
`.Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.END(xlUp).END(xlToRight)).Copy`.

The exact error is "Object Variable or With block variable not set"

Any help would be greatly appreciated. THANKS!

```
Dim appExcel As Excel.Application
Dim myWorkbook As Excel.Workbook
Dim rng as Range

With myWorkbook.Worksheets("qryAutoBuildFile")
myWorkbook.Sheets("qryAutoBuildFile").Activate
Set rng = Range("A1:CU1").Find("Article").Offset(0, 1)

     rng.Select
    .Range(rng, rng.END(xlUp).END(xlToRight)).Copy
    .Range("A1:CU1").Find("Expr1008").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    .Range("A1").Select
End With
    appExcel.CutCopyMode = False
```

Comment: Start with applying the advice [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Comment: @chrisneilsen yeah I know using Select isn't a great way of doing things. Normally I don't but in this case I don't know the syntax/function to combine both my lines to just copy directly what I want. If I try to use `.Range("A1:CU1").Find("Article").Offset(0, 1).copy` it won't select the exact cells I need and I need specific ones selected. Any thoughts on combining them?

Comment: What happens if you prefix `ActiveCell` in both places with dots? `.Range(.ActiveCell, .ActiveCell.END(xlUp).END(xlToRight)).Copy`

Comment: Dim a Range variable,  Set that to the result of the Find .  Substitute ActiveCell with that variable.

Comment: @HansUp had thought of that but get the same error. Good call though.

Comment: @chrisneilsen I setup a range variable like you suggested but I get the error "Method 'Range' of Object' _global failed". See updated code in my original post. The error pops on `Set rng = Range("A1:CU1").Find("Article").Offset(0, 1)
`

Comment: That would suggest "Article" was not found.  Try `Set Rng = .Range("A1:CU1").Find("Article")` `If Not Rng Is Nothing Then` `Set Rng = Rng.Offset(1, 0)` `Else` `MsgBox("Arcticle Not Found")` `End If`

Comment: @chrisneilsen your first suggestion was good. I just needed to define it a little more specifically. See my answer below. I added the workbook to the range variable and that cleared up the issue. It's all good now. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

There are several other issues with your code too.

1. Some parameters of `Find` require explicit setting.  [See here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find)
2. Use the With block
3. Account for possibility `Find` returns `Nothing`, twice

```
Dim appExcel As Excel.Application
Dim myWorkbook As Excel.Workbook
Dim rng as Excel.Range
Dim rngDest as Excel.Range

With myWorkbook.Worksheets("qryAutoBuildFile")
    '.Activate  ' use the With block, not really needed 
    Set rng = .Range("A1:CU1").Find(What:="Article", & _
      LookIn:=xlValues, & _
      LookAt:=xlWhole, & _
      SearchOrder:=xlByRows)
      ' Adjust to suit your needs.  Add MatchByte as well is you require double-byte language support
    If rng is Nothing then
        ' Not found, what now?
    Else
        Set rng = .Range(rng.Offset(0, 1), rng.END(xlToRight)) ' a bit shorter
        Set rngDest = .Range("A1:CU1").Find("Expr1008") 
         ' Don't need to specify Find parameters again, that previously specified onews will be used (unless you want to change them)

        If rngDest Is Nothing Then
            ' Not found, what now?
        Else
            rngDest.Value2 = rng.Value
        End If
    End If
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim appExcel As Excel.Application
Dim myWorkbook As Excel.Workbook
Dim rng as Range

With myWorkbook.Worksheets("qryAutoBuildFile")
myWorkbook.Sheets("qryAutoBuildFile").Activate
Set rng = myWorkbook.Worksheets("qryAutoBuildFile").Range("A1:CU1").Find("Article").Offset(0, 1)

     rng.Select
    .Range(rng, rng.END(xlUp).END(xlToRight)).Copy
    .Range("A1:CU1").Find("Expr1008").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    .Range("A1").Select
End With
    appExcel.CutCopyMode = False
```